# How did this old question end up in the reopen queue?

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

Today this question: [Java - Connecting javascript to servlet [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821570/java-connecting-javascript-to-servlet) showed up in the reopen queue.

It was closed as a duplicate (correctly) in 2016.

I'm curious as to whether there's any reason for this to be looked at again, other than "someone randomly clicked reopen for unfathomable reasons".

Comment: Martijn deleted it and undeleted it (unknown why), before re-opening and re-closing as a duplicate. It entered the re-open queue at the exact same time the re-closure happened. Why... idk

Comment: @Nick Thanks -- as my curiosity is partially satisfied, should I delete this Q?

Comment: Nah, the question is fine and still doesn't have a definitive answer for the why it being closed would put it in the reopen queue

Comment: There was [a glitch a few days ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369846/334566) that may be related. Also see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369848/334566) for a related bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is definitely a weird case, but not for reasons that are immediately obvious.

Based on the timeline, as [mentioned above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411588/how-did-this-old-question-end-up-in-the-reopen-queue#comment868204_411588) by [@Nick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3270037/nick):

[image: Screenshot of post timeline, indicating that the post being reopened and the post getting sent to review were simultaneous timeline events]

The reopen by Martijn<sup>1</sup> and the post getting sent to review were *simultaneous* events, which seems to confirm that it was indeed the reopen that sent it to the queue.

Via the [newly updated flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j3Fi.png) from the [Review Queue Workflows - Final Release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) post, a post should drop into the Reopen Votes queue when it receives either: 1) its first reopen vote or 2) an edit with the "Significant edit" checkbox checked.

Thus, it seems that Martijn's reopen vote, which was enough to single-handedly reopen the post, was counted the same as a standard vote to reopen, which created [the RV review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/29811309).

If this post had been reopened and *left* open, the respective RV queue review item [would have simply become invalidated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165653), because the post would have already been open. But in this case, presumably because the post was closed again so quickly (~8 seconds), the review item stuck around instead.

---

<sup>1 - There are [a number of reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361046) why a mod would reopen and then immediately close a post, even a previously closed one.</sup>

Comment: I have no idea, however, whether moderator closure/ reopen votes _should_ be creating respective review tasks, or whether that's a bug. I couldn't find record of it being one way or the other prior to the queue updates, after digging for a while on MSE.